# Building espresso under cygwin - confused

Tags: cygwin, mingw

I'm trying to build the espresso library under cygwin for windows. I've downloaded all needed packages (gcc, wingw32, etc.). After I did:
`./configure`

I've got "yes" everywhere, which means cygwin has everything I need. But how do I proceed next?

If I type: `make`

I end up with many errors like this:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h:376:
>   undefined       reference to `_filbuf'

Very suspicious, I have mingw not insde C:/mingw, but inside actual `C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.3` folder.

I suggest I'm using this `make` command wrong. Should I somehow set it explicitly to use mingw at the correct path?

I can confirm I have gcc installed:

```
Orvald@Orvald-PC /cygdrive/c/espresso
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.3

Orvald@Orvald-PC /cygdrive/c/espresso
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.3
```

Comment: I've founded the solution: $ ./configure --prefix=/mingw. I'll keep this question opened if someone ever searches for it.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it so people find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've founded the solution: $ ./configure --prefix=/mingw. I'll keep this question opened if someone ever searches for it. –